# KimonoLabs crawler Generated URL List with regex

Tags: regex, web-crawler

So, I'm trying to crawl a website that has like 7,000 product pages and the link structure is like this:

```
https://example.com/category/sub-category/numericid-name-of-the-product/
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to Generate a URL list, the Kimono App has that option, and it actually sections the URL but I'm only offered default value, range, and custom list.

[image: example]

I tried to put in stuff like **"/.+/"** to match all the chars, but that does not work, I couldn't find any help on that on official kb.

.I know that import.io had that "{alpahnumeric}" for example for different parts of URL so it matches them, is there a way to accomplish that in kimonolabs app?

Comment: any url regexp is: /.*/     Please provide a source code.

Comment: It's an app, as I've stated, there's no source code, you give it a URL and then generated based on that...

Comment: What I mean is that it's a windows native app, so yeah I don't have the source code, the title explicitly says I'm using "kimonolabs" - if someone wants to contribute to that needs to know what kimonolabs is, so asking for "source code" in a question that explicitly references to that app is a nonsense. So yeah, my crawler has no source code. App has it. Source code has only one URL that the app uses. Please don't be pedantic. If you can't help me, please don't make it any harder. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `https://example.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)`

Note: you may need to escape some characters (namely `/` would be escaped as `\/`).

Also, I'm not familiar with KimonoLabs, so I don't know if this is what you're looking for exactly. Feel free to clarify.

## Explanation

- `https://example.com/` literally
- `([^/]+)/` a bunch of not `/`s, followed by a `/`
- `([0-9]+)-([^/]+)` Numbers followed by another bunch of not `/`s